# how to create onload java script selected value in select tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

I created a select list. How to create `onload` function using javascript. When open the page selected value is `1`. At that time I need to show `no1` `div`. How to do that?

```js
function olresult(e) {
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("sel").value;

  if (selectedValue == '1') {
    document.getElementById('no1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('no2').style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    document.getElementById('no1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('no2').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="sel" onload="olresult(event)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="no1" style="display:none;">
  <p>123</p>
</div>
<div id="no2" style="display:none;">
  <p>aaaaa</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just removing the `display:none;` from `div#no1`?

Comment: I need to show `no1` div. when onload selected value 1. If you selected value 2, I need to show `no2` div.

Comment: I think any one dont know the answer

Answer (score 0):

`<select>` elements don't work with `onload`, you want to fire the event when the selection changes. You need to change `onload` to `onchange`.

If you need something to happen when the page loads, you can add `onload` to the `<body>` element or better yet just include your script to run at the end of the HTML document. Also, you may as well just remove `display:none` from the HTML.

```js
function olresult(e) {
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("sel").value;

  if (selectedValue == '1') {
    document.getElementById('no1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('no2').style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    document.getElementById('no1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('no2').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="sel" onchange="olresult(event)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="no1" style="display:none;">
  <p>123</p>
</div>
<div id="no2">
  <p>aaaaa</p>
</div>
```

Comment: that you for the answer. But, This is not the answer my friend. I dont know which value will show. therefore We need to write `onload` function here. How write that?

Comment: As already stated in the answer, you can add `onload` to your `<body>` element. `<body onload="olresult(event)">`. The proper way to do it would be to include JavaScript at the end of the page and listen for `DOMContentLoaded` - you can find plenty of tutorials online for how to do this.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information than "not working properly." What isn't working properly? Are you getting any errors?